# Query:adding empty list item

Tags: jquery, html

I'm updating a select box from it's document's child (thickbox)

```
var opt = "<option value='8'>TEST<option>";
parent.jQuery("#my_teams_list").prepend(opt);
```

Here "my_teams_list" is the id of the parent document's select box.

While doing this an empty list item is added inside of the select box.

I don't know why. Please clear me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:
EDIT

```
parent.jQuery("#my_teams_list").prepend($("<option></option>").text("test").val("test"));
```

Comment: I have just done this in one of my forms and it works - note I added Selected --- $("#Product_SizeGroupId").prepend($("<option></option>").text("TEST").val("TEST").attr("selected","selected"));

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your list is (assume <select>) you want to prepend child element not just text so instead of prepending "TEST" prepend "<option>TEST</option>".